# Please help my animation is not working ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have an issue. I'm using animation block, but the second animation simultaneously animates with the first animation.

This is my code.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(63, 59, 437, 289);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                         [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                         [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
                         self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(63, 2, 437, 289);
                         [UIScrollView commitAnimations];
                     }
                }]
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you using mixed animation styles? Use the block animation for the 2nd one too.

Comment: also, where do you change the `finished` boolean ?

Comment: @rmaddy, can you please give me the code, because I'm still confused using animation block. Thanks.

Comment: Inside your `if (finished)` statement, simply call `[UIView animationWithDuration...` again instead of using `[UIScrollView beginAnimations]` / `[UIScrollView commitAnimations]`.

Comment: It didn't work. Animation still runs simultaneously.

Comment: BTW - I never said it was the problem. I simply pointed out that you should stick to one style of animations.

Comment: A same scrollView with simultaneously animates?

Comment: Hi, @simalone. the animations intends to position the scrollview to its default position after positioning it to its second position.

Answer (score 2):

Maddy told you what to do. The nested block syntax can be hard to figure out, so cheat:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(63, 59, 437, 289);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) 
                     {
                         [self secondAnimation];
                     }
                }]


- (void) secondAnimation:
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.6
    animations: ^
    {
      self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(63, 2, 437, 289);
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: "It didn't work" is perhaps the least informative way you can possibly describe a problem. How about some details on what it did?

Comment: i added an NSLog in the first animation and in second. after i run the program, both NSLog displays at the same time. 2014-03-19 10:40:07.845 MedsRUs[4485:70b] first animation
2014-03-19 10:40:07.846 MedsRUs[4485:70b] second animation

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on. The code I posted should work, and the secondAnimation method should not be called until the first animation finishes. Time to create a new project that ONLY has this animation in it, get that working, and then figure out what's different about your project.

Comment: What do you see? Any animation at all? Does it jump to the first position and then the second? What happens if you remove the second animation?

Answer (score 0):

Add an NSLog that displays `self.scrollView.frame` before the first animation.  If you don't actually change anything in an animation, I think it will just get skipped.